# Angular 6 Cannot Read Property 'userEmail' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

Code:

```
// Angular Modules
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';

// Services
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.less']
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Profile';
  showError = false;
  showSuccess = false;
  showAccountRemovalModal = false;

  profileForm: FormGroup;
  passwordForm: FormGroup;
  removeAccountForm: FormGroup;
  user: Object;
  userEmail: String;
  errorMessage: String;
  successMessage: String;

  constructor(private TitleService: Title,
              private fb: FormBuilder,
              private authService: AuthService) {

    // Creates the profileForm schema with validations.
    this.profileForm = this.fb.group({
      name: [{value: null, disabled: false}, Validators.required],
      username: [{value: null, disabled: true}, Validators.required],
      email: [{value: null, disabled: false}, [Validators.required, Validators.email]]
    });

    // Creates the passwordForm schema with validations.
    this.passwordForm = this.fb.group({
      passwords: fb.group({
        password: [null, [Validators.required]],
        confirmPassword: [null, [Validators.required]]
      }, {validator: this.passwordMatchValidator})
    });

    // Creates the removeAccountForm schema with validations.
    this.removeAccountForm = this.fb.group({
      emailAddress: fb.group({
        verifyEmail: [null, [Validators.required]]
      }, {validator: this.emailMatchValidator})
    });
  }

  // Compares the password and confirmPassword fields for a match.
  passwordMatchValidator(form: FormGroup) {
    return form.controls['password'].value === form.controls['confirmPassword'].value ? null : {
      'mismatch': true
    };
  }

  // Compares the entered email address field for account removal.
  emailMatchValidator(form: FormGroup) {
    return form.controls['verifyEmail'].value === this.userEmail ? null : {
      'mismatch': true
    };
  }

  // Updates the profile of the User.
  updateProfile(id, name, email) {
    const user = {
      name: name,
      email: email,
    };

    this.authService.updateUser(id, user).subscribe(data => {
      if (data) {
        console.log(data);
        this.successMessage = 'Your profile information has been updated!';
        this.showSuccess = true;
      } else {
        this.errorMessage = data.msg;
        this.showError = true;
      }
    });
  }

  removeUser(id) {
    this.authService.removeUser(id);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Gets the current User object.
    this.authService.getUser().subscribe(profile => {
      this.user = profile;
      this.userEmail = profile.email;
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err);
      return false;
    });

    // Sets the page title.
    this.TitleService.setTitle('WODGate - ' + this.title);
  }
}
```

At the bottom, in my `ngOnInit`, I'm pushing a string to u`serEmail` which is valid.  `console.log(profile.email)` returns a valid string.  The error I'm getting comes from the `emailMatchValidator` function where I'm trying to read `this.userEmail`.  Actually, even if I try to read `this.user` anywhere in my .ts file I get the same error.  In my HTML, I have to read the values using the `?` operator such as `user?.email` for it to work.

I need to be able to read `this.userEmail` in my .ts file but I'm getting the error *"Cannot Read Property 'userEmail' of undefined"*.

Here is the function from my service for reference:

```
// Return Single User
  getUser() {
    const headers = new Headers();
    this.loadToken();
    headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken);
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:4000/api/users/' + this.user.id, {headers: headers})
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`emailMatchValidator` function have lost its context - means that `this` is not showing to the component now. You need to bind the context explicitly or use `arrow function`.

Using explicitly binding

```
{ validator: this.emailMatchValidator.bind(this) })
```

you say that `this` will show to the given value to the `bind` function - in our case to the `ProfileComponent`.

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thank you!